# Shortest method to implement the Pythagorean Theorem

Tags: code-golf, math

Who doesn't love the Pythagorean theorem \$a^2+b^2=c^2\$? Write the shortest method you can in any language that takes in value `a` and `b` and prints out `The hypotenuse of this right triangle is c`.  Keep `c` to only three decimal places.

Comment: Shortest in characters or bytes? :)

Comment: shortest in characters

Comment: The `code-golf` tag explicitly says *"Code-golf is a competition to solve a particular problem in the fewest **bytes** of source code."* See [Scoring code golf (bytes vs. characters)](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/942/scoring-code-golf-bytes-vs-characters).

Answer (score 14):

### APL (54)

```
'The hypotenuse of this right triangle is',3⍕.5*⍨+/⎕*2
```

Test:

```
      'The hypotenuse of this right triangle is',3⍕.5*⍨+/⎕*2
⎕:
      9 10
The hypotenuse of this right triangle is 13.454
```

Explanation:

- `⎕*2`: raise the values in the input to the second power
- `+/`: take the sum
- `.5*⍨`: raise the result to the 0.5th power
- `3⍕`: round to 3 decimal places

Comment: This is about unbeatable

Comment: @Cruncher: I tried to encode the string but couldn't get the decoding routine small enough.

Comment: By the pigeon hole principle, I think you'd have a really hard time (maybe impossible. It has to be impossible for at least some strings) trying to compress the string. Maybe if the string had some logical pattern, but that doesn't appear to be the case. I'm interested to see the attempts you've had so far though

Comment: Correct the spelling of "hypotenuse" to save a character.

Comment: Hmm. Since all of these characters are in the range 65-122, You can encode about 4 characters into a byte(map the 65-122 into 0-63). Making your string about 32 characters shorter. The question is if you can decode those bytes back into a string in 30 chars.

Comment: Actually it may be better than that. Most chars are in 97 to 122. You can hard code the "T".

Comment: @Cruncher Huh? 4 characters per byte would mean 2 bits per character... unless you're using really big bytes :)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Oops. I done goofed. I was thinking that 64 is 1/4th of 256. Doesn't work like that. It's more than half of the bits. Yeah, there's no way to compress and decode it

Comment: @Cruncher: I'd have to re-encode the spaces. But I already tried something like this (packing four characters into an Unicode character) and the decoding routine was too long.

Comment: @marinus ah the spaces sound like a pain. If the string was longer it may be worth it.

Comment: @Cruncher: I'd ended up with this: `'T',⊃,/{(⎕UCS 32,96+⍳26)[1+2⊥5 4⍴(20/2)⊤⍵]}¨⎕UCS'鐄坪'`. It can still be shortened a bit but obviously not by enough.

Comment: Is this a reusable method or just a one off statement?

Comment: @Cruncher: Actually, I beat it in Sclipting...

Comment: Good example of why some of us love APL!

Answer (score 11):

## TI-BASIC, <s>76</s> <s>55</s> <s>53</s> 52 bytes

```
Input :Disp "THE HYPOTENUSE OF THIS RIGHT TRIANGLE IS
Fix 3:R▶Pr(X,Y
```

No, a closing parentheses is not required. Also, less bytes than that APL answer :)

Comment: Could be `R▶Pr(A,B`.

Comment: 2 years to implement a suggestion, lol.

Comment: Destined for greatness, I guess. And I just shaved off two more bytes to beat APL!

Comment: -1 byte: `Fix 3:R►Pr(X,Y`

Comment: Using `Input` to ask for `X` and `Y` is kind of hilarious. If we allow that, should we also allow setting `PolarGC` before `Input`, so that the length of the hypotenuse is given by the one-byte `R`? Admittedly, with `PolarGC` the values of `X` and `Y` are no longer *displayed* when we move the cursor around, but they're still *stored* to the appropriate variables. (Which we would then never use, but it's the thought that counts.)

Comment: @MishaLavrov I suppose. The really funny thing would be if `R` was auto-calculated from the regular `Input` for something like `Input :R`

Answer (score 9):

## Python 2.7 - 76 Characters

```
print'The hypotenuse of this right triangle is %.3f'%abs(input()+1j*input())
```

**Explanation**

$$|a+bi| = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2} = c \\
\implies a^2 + b^2 = c^2$$

**PJ on hypotenuse**

> Teacher: "Can you tell me, what is hypotenuse?"
>
> LJ: "Hypotenuse, an easy question. If there's a high profile party last night, and you
> read it in the news paper, its called High Party
> News"

Answer (score 8):

## [Sclipting](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Sclipting), 46 characters

```
글坼各갠方終加감半方갾밈乘增貶껠矽녆둥긆둹댆뭴뉖멵댶넠닶눠덆둩댲걲늖덨덂건댦땡닦덬뉒걩댲밀⓶
```

Expects the input as two numbers (can be fractional!) separated by a space.

This is shorter than APL, despite having to use a few inconvenient tricks.

### Explanation

```
글坼 | split at space
各 | for each...
  갠方 | to the power of two
終
加 | add
감半方 | to the power of one half
갾밈乘 | multiply by 1000
增貶 | increment, then decrement (kludge for rounding)
껠矽 | insert '.' at 4th-last character position
녆둥긆둹댆뭴뉖멵댶넠닶눠덆둩댲걲늖덨덂건댦땡닦덬뉒걩댲밀⓶ | "The hypotenuse..."
```

Comment: doesn't unicode make this like 92 bytes?

Comment: @Cruncher I asked yesterday up in the question comments, what counts is character count, not byte count.

Answer (score 4):

## dc 54

Tangents the score of the APL answer!

```
2^r2^+3kv[The hypotenuse of this right triangle is ]Pp
```

Test:

```
$ dc
3 4
2^r2^+3kv[The hypotenuse of this right triangle is ]Pp
The hypotenuse of this right triangle is 5.000
```

Comment: doesn' really work for me. `dc -e '2^r2^+3kv[The hypotenuse of this right triangle is ]Pp'` doesn't wait for any input, prints `"dc: stack empty"` 3 times and then "The hypotenuse of this right triangle is 2.000".

Comment: @Tomas it's sort of a a function; you need to put the parameters on the stack first, like I show in the test, or if you want to invoke your way, it would be `dc -e '3 4 2^r2^+3kv[...` where 3 and 4 are the parameters.

Answer (score 3):

### C, 77 or 99

77 characters if input can just be the function arguments:

```
f(a,b){printf("The hypotenuse of this right triangle is %.3f\n",hypot(a,b));}
```

99 if input must be read from stdin:

```
a,b;f(){scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);printf("The hypotenuse of this right triangle is %.3f\n",hypot(a,b));}
```

A big thanks to @Yimin Rong!

Comment: There is a hypot(a,b) which will save you three characters.

Comment: That function not compile whatever compile I use gcc tcc clang in tio...perhaps lack one #include header and in the title the precise version of the compiler

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, <del>94</del> <del>90</del> 82 chars

```
p "The hypotenuse of this right triangle is %.3f"%(Math.sqrt(gets.to_i**2+gets.to_i**2))
```

Update (thanks for the comments):

```
p "The hypotenuse of this right triangle is %.3f"%(gets.to_i**2+gets.to_i**2)**0.5
```

Comment: You could save a few chars if you use `a**0.5` instead of lengthy `Math.sqrt(a)`. And the space after `p` can also be removed.

Comment: And you do not need parenthesis in `%(Math...)`.

Answer (score 3):

**Powershell**

Just to see if i could...

```
echo "The hypotenuse of this right triangle is " ([math]::round([math]::sqrt(([math]::pow(([double](Read-Host -p "A")),2) + [math]::pow(([double](Read-Host -p "B")),2))),3))
```

Comment: Nice work. Looks like you did this while I was busy with my own solution, which beats this by about 62 characters. For future reference, Code Golf answers are expected to be "golfed" and have their "score" included. "Golfing" means that you should make every effort to reduce the character length by using short-hand aliases, syntax tricks, and other means of stretching the language's rules. You should also remove unnecessary whitespace where possible (there's at least three spaces that can be removed from your solution). The "score", in this case, is your character count - currently 173.

Comment: I suggest reading the code golf tag wiki, various portions of the Help Center, and the Golfing Tips for PowerShell thread to get a better feel for how to write a competitive answer to code golf challenges here.

Comment: Also, I get an error with your script. "...the parameter name 'p' is ambiguous..." with regards to `Read-Host`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Whispers v2](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Whispers), <sup><s>133</s></sup>, 93 bytes

```
> Input
> Input
> "The hypotenuse of this right triangle is %.3f"
>> 1⊿2
>> 3%4
>> Output 5
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8/ILC5ILSo2@v/fTsEzr6C0hAtBK4VkpCpkVBbkl6TmlRanKuSnKZQA1SsUZaZnlCiUFGUm5qXnpCoARVT1jNOUuOzsFAwfde03AjGMVU1AlH9pCdAsBdP//425TAE)

<del>The major part of this program is calculating the decimal point's index and truncating to 3 digits.</del> -40 bytes from Leo!

Comment: Or you could "cheat" :) https://tio.run/##K8/ILC5ILSo2@v/fTsEzr6C0hAtBK4VkpCpkVBbkl6TmlRanKuSnKZQA1SsUZaZnlCiUFGUm5qXnpCoARVT1jNOUuOzsFAwfde03AjGMVU1AlH9pCdAsBdP//425TAE

Comment: That's a thing?!

Comment: Apparently `%` directly calls `%` from python, [Jo King found this out](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/194126/62393)

Answer (score 2):

## C++ - 90

```
void h(int a,int b){printf("The hypotenuse of this right triangle is %.3f\n",hypot(a,b));}
```

Comment: `pow(a,2)` when you can do `a*a`? I'm also not sure I understand the purpose of the floor and the +.5 and the multiply and divide by 1000

Comment: @Cruncher The floor is to set the decimal place to .3 places.  I am reworking it right now, and will include your suggestion.

Comment: There is a hypot(a,b) which will save you three characters.

Comment: @YiminRong Cool!

Answer (score 2):

### MATLAB <s>79</s> 74

```
@(a,b)sprintf('The hypotenuse of this right triangle is %.3f',norm([a b]))
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2.7 - 80 chars

```
print'The hypotenuse of this right triangle is %.3f'%(input()**2+input()**2)**.5
```

Comment: I don't think this does 3 decimal places...?

Comment: It's my fault, I've corrected, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

## Perl 6 (<del>68</del> 74 bytes)

```
{printf "The hypotenuse of this right triangle is %.3f
",sqrt [+] @_ X**2}
```

`{}` declares a lambda function. `[+]` is sum operator, `X**` is cross power operator (for example, `1, 2 X+ 10, 20` gives `11, 21, 12, 22`). In this case, cross power operator takes one argument, so the result has the same length as `@_`. `@_` contains all function arguments.

If it's disallowed to have function that may take wrong number of arguments (unsafe), it's possible to replace `[+] @_ X**2` with `$^a**2+$^b**2`, where `$^a` and `$^b` are placeholder arguments.

Comment: How would you limit to 3 decimal places?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: I fail at reading. Should be fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

### EcmaScript 6, <strike>82</strike> 79

```
f=(a,b)=>"The hypotenuse of this right triangle is "+Math.hypot(a,b).toFixed(3)
```

Usage:

```
f(3, 5)
> "The hypotenuse of this right triangle is 5"
```

**Update:** Switch to `Math.hypot()`

Answer (score 2):

**Golfscript (<s>69 67 66</s> 65)**

This would be much easier if floating point was actually supported without resorting to workarounds... :)

```
~'The hypotenuse of this right triangle is '@.*@.*+2-1??+.'.'?4+<
```

[A link to test it](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=OyIzIDUiCgp%2BJ1RoZSBoeXBvdGVudXNlIG9mIHRoaXMgcmlnaHQgdHJpYW5nbGUgaXMgJ0AuKkAuKisyLTE%2FPysuJy4nPzQrPA%3D%3D).

Comment: why are you doing `2.!~` when `2-1` is shorter?

Comment: @McKay Good question, I always get`the difference between `2- 1` and `2-1` wrong, so was probably temporarily confused :) Fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**Javascript (97)**

```
x=prompt;a=x(),b=x();x('The hypotenuse of this right triangle is '+Math.sqrt(a*a+b*b).toFixed(3))
```

Comment: .toFixed .. thank you! learned something new :)

Answer (score 2):

### C, 100 chars (beats the other C solution by 1!)

A ridiculously inefficient algorithm.

```
x;f(a,b){for(;x-a*a-b*b;x=rand());printf("The hypotenuse of this right triangle is %.3f",sqrt(x));}
```

Comment: Sorry, but you've written "the" instead of "this", so if you correct that it's the same length ;P

Comment: @daniero Ok, found a fix, now still one char down :)

Comment: In the Borland C compiler it would not compile...

Answer (score 2):

### DELPHI / PASCAL

#### With indent (157)

```
program p;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
var a,b:integer;
begin
     readln(a,b);
     writeln('the hypotenuse of this right triangle is',sqrt(b*b+a*a):2:3);
end.
```

Comment: ah man, i had the exact same :(

Comment: to late for an edit, so again.. 
Edit: You can get 2 characters off by changing `integer` to `int16` You dont have to include the first 2 lines for your answer, and you can remove whitespace. doing all that gives you 106 characters.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2 (79)

```
def p(a,b):print'The hypotenuse of this right triangle is %.3d'%((a*a+b*b)**.5)
```

Comment: Dispense with `math` for some savings.  `(a*a+b*b)**.5`

Comment: Since the body of your function is a single statement, it can be on the same line as the `def` saving a newline and an indent.

Answer (score 1):

## AWK — <del>84</del> 78 characters

```
awk '{printf"The hypotenuse of this right triangle is %.3f\n",($1^2+$2^2)^.5}'
```

Thanks to Wasi for suggesting ^ operator and removing ()!

e.g.

```
$ echo 3 4 | awk '{printf"The hypotenuse of this right triangle is %.3f\n",($1^2+$2^2)^.5}'
The hypotenuse of this right triangle is 5.000
```

Comment: You can golf it further `{printf"The hypotenuse of this right triangle is %.3f\n",($1^2+$2^2)^.5}`

Answer (score 1):

**C#**

**Method Only (114)**

```
void H(double a, double b)
{
    Console.Write("The hypotenuse of this right triangle is {0:N3}", Math.Sqrt(a * a + b * b)); 
}
```

**Complete Program (171)**

```
using System;
class P
{        
   static void H(double a, double b)
   {
     Console.Write("The hypotenuse of this right triangle is {0:N3}", Math.Sqrt(a * a + b * b));
   }                
   static void Main()
   {
    H(3, 4);
   }
}
```

**Complete Program (without using method - 141)**

```
using System;class P{static void Main(){double a=3,b=4;Console.Write("The hypotenuse of this right triangle is {0:N3}",Math.Sqrt(a*a+b*b));}}
```

Comment: Heres my complete program. 141 chars...you can save a few chars using the formatstring overload of write  using System;class P{static void Main(){double a=3,b=4;Console.Write("The hypotenuse of this right triangle is {0:N3}",Math.Sqrt(a*a+b*b));}}

Comment: You can use string formatting in the Console.Write instead of calling ToString() to save 9 characters.

Answer (score 1):

## PowerShell: 111

**Golfed Code**

```
1..2|%{sv $_ (read-host)};"The hypotenuse of this right triangle is $("{0:N3}"-f[math]::sqrt($1/1*$1+$2/1*$2))"
```

**Walkthrough**

`1..2|%{sv $_ (read-host)};` Gets two inputs interactively from the user, and stores them in $1 and $2. Might be able to cut some length by using arguments or pipeline inputs instead.

`"The hypotenuse of this right triangle is` Required text in the output, per the challenge specifications.

`$(`...`)"` Encapsulated code block will be processed as script before being included in the output.

`"{0:N3}"-f` Formats output from the next bit of code as a number with exactly three digits after the decimal point.

`[math]::sqrt(`...`)` Gets the square root of the encapsulated value.

`$1/1*$1+$2/1*$2` Serves as our "a^2+b^2". Multiplying a number by itself is the shortest way to square it in PowerShell, but the variables need to be divided by 1 first to force them to integers. Otherwise, they are treated as text and 3*3+4*4 would be 3334444 instead of 25.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript <strike>118</strike> <strike>106</strike> 93

Unlike @micha's solution, mine takes in two variables via function and sends the alert of the result.

<strike>`function(a,b){m=Math;c=d=>d*d,e=1e3;alert("The hypotenuse of this right triangle is "+m.round(m.sqrt(c(a)+c(b))*e)/e)}`</strike>

<strike>`function(a,b){e=1e3;alert("The hypotenuse of this right triangle is "+Math.round(Math.sqrt(a*a+b*b)*e)/e)}`</strike>

Fat arrow functions to the rescue!

`h=(a,b,e=1e3)=>"The hypotenuse of this right triangle is "+Math.round(Math.sqrt(a*a+b*b)*e)/e`

Comment: Could be shorter if you inline `c()`. Aliasing `Math` doesn't save bytes in your case.

Comment: @Florent Ah, yes... one sec!

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript: 83

```
i=prompt,'The hypotenuse of this right triangle is '+Math.hypot(i(),i()).toFixed(3)
```

Currently the shortest JS implementation using `stdin` :D
Works only on Firefox 27.0+ (EcmaScript 6)

### JavaScript: 78

If we can use just two variables (as lot of scripts do here):

```
a=2,b=3,'The hypotenuse of this right triangle is '+Math.hypot(a,b).toFixed(3)
```

Comment: whoooo .. .hypot. Good catch!

Answer (score 1):

## dc, 55

```
3k?d*?d*+v[The hypotenuse of this right triangle is ]Pp
```

Answer (score 1):

### Java, 112

(Also prints out a No Such Method error, though I'm not sure if this is against the rules)

```
class A{static{int a=1,b=1;System.out.printf("The hypotenuse of this right triangle is %.3f",Math.hypot(a,b));}}
```

### Java, 149

(No error)

```
class A{static{int a=1,b=1;System.out.printf("The hypotenuse of this right triangle is %.3f",Math.hypot(a,b));}public static void main(String[] a){}}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### c64 basic v2, <strike>60</strike> 66 bytes

```
0inputa,b:?"The hypotenuse of this right triangle is";sQ(a*a+b*b)
```

Screenshot:

[image]

[How to try it.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/142638/14149)

Comment: should say "The hypotenuse of this *right* triangle is"

Comment: @Mayube Sad :-( +6 byte :-( Post fixed.

Answer (score 1):

## R, <s>61</s> 76 bytes

```
cat("The hypotenuse of this right triangle is",round(sqrt(sum(scan()^2)),3))
```

`cat` displays its content to STDOUT.

The `scan()` function takes user's input from keyboard. This input exists as a vector, on which the `^2` is applied (`^`function is vectorized), and the `sum()` sums the elements of the vector. `sqrt` outputs the square-root, which is rounded to 3 decimal places by `round(,3)`

Thanks to @caird coinheringaahing for noticing that the previous answer didn't round.

Comment: Does this "Keep c to only three decimal places."?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing : it does now ! Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

## [ARBLE](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/ARBLE), <s>73</s> 60 bytes

```lua
"The hypotenuse of this right triangle is %.3f"%(a^2+b^2)^.5
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyxKykn9/18pJCNVIaOyIL8kNa@0OFUhP02hJCOzWKEoMz2jRKGkKDMxLz0nVQEooqpnnKakqpEYZ6SdFGekGadn@v//f@P/JgA)

Comment: @H.PWiz I must say, for a challenge that should just be `sqrt(a^2+b^2)`, this has a lot of unnecessary boilerplate.

Answer (score 1):

## [OML](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/OML), 57 bytes

```
"The hypotenuse of this right triangle is "shnhn+A6`*N3eD
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8/N@f9fKSQjVSGjsiC/JDWvtDhVIT9NoSQjs1ihKDM9o0ShpCgzMS89J1UBKKJUnJGXkaftaJag5Wec6vL/v6GCIQA)

### Part 1

This simply outputs the string

```
"The hypotenuse of this right triangle is "s
```

### Part 2

```
hnhn+A6`*N3eD
hn              take input and square it
  hn            take another input and square it
    +           add them
     A6`        push 10^6
        *       multiply the sum with that number
         N      take integer square root
          3eD   output with three places of precision
                implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 32 characters

```
,²S½ær3µ,“¡ÆC⁷⁺ɱSoṿȤç½?⁶Ẏtḍỵŀ»ṚK
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AUsAtP9qZWxsef//LMKyU8K9w6ZyM8K1LOKAnMKhw4ZD4oG34oG6ybFTb@G5v8ikw6fCvT/igbbhuo504biN4bu1xYDCu@G5mkv///8z/zQ)

There is probably a better string compression that allows me to get around needing to join with spaces but I was having trouble finding it.

**Explanation:**

```
,²S½ær3µ,“...»ṚK    Example inputs: 3, 4
,                   Pair the inputs. Result: [3, 4]
 ²                  Square them. Result: [9, 16]
  S                 Sum them. Result: 25
   ½                Get the square root of the sum. Result: 5
    ær3             Round to 3 decimal places. Result: 5
       µ            Take the result of that... Result: 5
         “...»       ...and  the compressed string Result: "The hypotenuse of this right triangle is"
        ,           And put them into a pair. Result: [5, "The hypotenuse of this right triangle is"]
              Ṛ     Reverse that. Result: ["The hypotenuse of this right triangle is", 5]
               k    Join it with spaces. Result: "The hypotenuse of this right triangle is 5.0"
                    Implicit output.
```

Comment: So long as `only three decimal places` means `less than or equal to three decimal places`, the output looks fine.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 70 bytes

```js
(a,b)=>'The hypotenuse of the triangle is '+((a*a+b*b)**.5).toFixed(3)
```

The latter function rounds the number to 3 decimal places.

Comment: It would be shorter to use addition instead of a template string.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, 70 bytes now

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), <s>32</s> 30 bytes

```
∆/`λƛ h⁼Ǐ¢Ṗλ₇ of λ× ¬ẋ Ȧ⇩ is Π
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwi4oiGL2DOu8abIGjigbzHj8Ki4bmWzrvigocgb2YgzrvDlyDCrOG6iyDIpuKHqSBpcyDOoCIsIiIsIlszLCA0XSJd)

Comment: [30 bytes with an (undocumented) feature](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwi4oiGL2DOu8abIGjigbzHj8Ki4bmWzrvigocgb2YgzrvDlyDCrOG6iyDIpuKHqSBpcyDOoCIsIiIsIlszLCA0XSJd): string interpolation

Answer (score 1):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), \$36\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 29.632 bytes

```
+qDFQ$XS)s2lSXreS8x%twBEZ:x@KUX"mqS*
```

[Try it online!](https://fig.fly.dev/#WyIrcURGUSRYUylzMmxTWHJlUzh4JXR3QkVaOnhAS1VYXCJtcVMqIiwiWzMsNF0iXQ==)

Answer (score 0):

### Javascript, 109

```
A=1,B=1,s=1e3,console.log("The hypotenuse of this right triangle is " + (Math.round(Math.sqrt(A*A+B*B)*s)/s))
```

[Fiddledee](http://jsfiddle.net/38e78/1/)

Comment: with `alert` you could save 6 chars

Comment: Down to 101: `A=1,B=1,s=1e3;alert("The hypotenuse of this right triangle is "+(Math.round(Math.sqrt(A*A+B*B)*s)/s))`

Comment: Using suggestions from other entries so far I get it to 90:
`A=1,B=1;alert("The hypotenuse of this right triangle is "+(Math.sqrt(A*A+B*B).toFixed(3)))`
Even less if you leave out alert

Answer (score 0):

### Scala (95c)

```
import Math._;val x=sqrt(pow(a,2)+pow(b,2));f"The hypotenuse of this right triangle is $x%1.3g"
```

Answer (score 0):

### Java : 223

```
   class l {
        public static void main(String[] args) {      
          new l().H(2,4);
        }   
        void H(float a, float b)
    {
        System.out.printf("The hypotenuse of this right triangle is %.3f",Math.hypot(a,b));
    }
    }
```

Comment: I brought this to 170 by making it a one liner, changing the method to a static: class h{public static void main(String[]args){H(2,4);}static void H(float a,float b){System.out.printf("The hypotenuse of this right triangle is %.3f",Math.hypot(a,b));}}

Comment: @Michaël Demey, hah, i didnt think of that changing the function to static .

Answer (score 0):

### newLISP, 103 characters

```
(let(a 3.1 b 4)(println"The hypotenuse of this right triangle is "(round(pow(add(pow a)(pow b)).5)-3)))
```

The unspecified input method helps a lot... :)

Answer (score 0):

### Groovy : 78 Characters

```
a={x,y->printf"The hypotenuse of this right triangle is %.3f",Math.hypot(x,y)}
```

Assuming the task is just writing a method. If you need to take input parameters:

**99 Characters**

```
printf"The hypotenuse of this right triangle is %.3f",Math.hypot(args[0].toLong(),args[1].toLong())
```

I found two ways to it with the same length:

```
printf"The hypotenuse of this right triangle is %.3f",Math.sqrt(args.collect{it.toLong()**2}.sum())
```

Answer (score 0):

## F#, 78

```
let f a b=sqrt(a*a+b*b)|>printf"The hypotenuse of this right triangle is %.3f"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Java : 155**

```
class A{A(int x,int y){System.out.printf("The hypotenuse of this right triangle is %.3f",Math.hypot(x,y));}public static void main(String[]s){new A(1,4);}}
```

Comment: You can take out the `public ` on the constructor saving 7

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript 98 characters/bytes

This is implemented as a browser alert in a function.

```
function p(a,b){alert('The hypotenuse of this right triangle is: '+Math.sqrt(a*a+b*b).toFixed(3))};
```

Answer (score 0):

## Fortran (90)

```
read(*,*)a,b;print'(a,f9.3)',"The hypotenuse of this right triangle is ",sqrt(a*a+b*b);end
```

Uses implicit typing so that `a,b` are single precision reals.

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript, 110 bytes

```
function h(a,b){return a/1==a&&b/1==b?'The hypotenuse of this right triangle is '+(a*a+b*b||0).toFixed(3):!1;}
```

It's a monster!!!

But it can handle NaN and invalid numbers, like text, objects, 0/0 and other invalid numbers.

Answer (score 0):

#### Ruby 2.1+ (73 characters)

```
f=->a,b{puts"The hypotenuse of this right triangle is %.3f"%(a+b*1i).abs}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Prolog

```
h(A,B):-X is A*A+B*B, C is sqrt(X),format('The hypotenuse of this right triangle is ~3f',C).
```

Answer (score 0):

## Bash with `bc`, 91

No bash script yet?!

```bsh
read a b
echo -n 'The hypotenuse of this right triangle is '
bc<<<"scale=3;sqrt($a^2+$b^2)"
```

There is no way this can win.

Comment: To save 1 character, you could use `printf` instead of `echo -n`.

Comment: Instead of `bc`, use `dc`: `dc<<<"3k$a d*$b d*+vp"`

Answer (score 0):

**Haskell, 77 characters**

```
(\x y->print$"The hypotenuse of this right triangle is "++(show$sqrt$x^2+y^2))
```

Useage:

```
(\x y->print$"The hypotenuse of this right triangle is "++(show$sqrt$x^2+y^2)) 3.0 4.0
The hypotenuse of this right triangle is 5.0
```

Answer (score 0):

## Fortran 2008 (87 characters)

Based on the Fortran 90 solution, but now in Fortran 2008, HYPOT is an intrinsic function.

```
read(*,*)a,b;print'(a,f9.3)','The hypotenuse of this right triangle is ',hypot(a,b);end
```

Answer (score 0):

## J, 56 bytes

```
'The hypotenuse of this right triangle is '&,@":@(+&.*:)
```

#### explanation

J's "Under" verb `&.` is a nice fit here.  It applies a transformation, executes a verb, and then applies the reverse transformation to the result. In this case, squaring is the transformation `*:`, its reverse is taking the square root, and the verb in question is addition.  So we do addition "under" the square transformation.  The rest is just formatting the number and cat'ing it onto the sentence.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P81WT0E9JCNVIaOyIL8kNa@0OFUhP02hJCOzWKEoMz2jRKGkKDMxLz0nVQEooq6m46Bk5aChraanZaXJlZqcka9grJCmYPL/PwA)

Comment: `|@j.` is even nicer.

Comment: @FrownyFrog that is wonderful, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 69 bytes

```perl
printf"The hypotenuse of this right triangle is %.3f",sqrt<>**2+<>**2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@gKDOvJE0pJCNVIaOyIL8kNa@0OFUhP02hJCOzWKEoMz2jRKGkKDMxLz0nVQEooqpnnKakU1xYVGJjp6VlpA0m//835jIBAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 80 bytes

```
puts "The hypotenuse of this right triangle is [expr int(hypot($a,$b)*1e3)/1e3]"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYpBCoAgFAX3neIhLjKCiKCTtIsWFr8UwkS/UKc3azMDw/B25kgMjbH6vGLIPnGEmAzBPP5icikSrh1sbESwh2FwsNodJ6GUmW4fYB3X/15L3cpVNT0NqitYRM4v)

Comment: I doubt that setting variables is an allowed I/O method... Nevertheless, your program does not seem to `[k]eep c to only three decimal places`.

Comment: @JonathanFrech: Fixed the 3 decimal places issue. About the setting variables issue, I will wait feedback from questions asker, as it seems I've seen some answers here doing the same.

Answer (score 0):

## [Jq 1.5](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 80 bytes

```
"The hypotenuse of this right triangle is \(1e3*pow(map(.*.)|add;.5)|floor/1e3)"
```

Assumes input is `[a,b]`

Try it online at [**tio.run**](https://tio.run/##FYmxDsIgFAB3v4J0gqZgam06@Btu1YGktGCQh/BIY8K3i3S63N3rU@ahuz670zx2/eXgdDCX5q4V0V8PqFyKisBKUJtIgtk0EgxGus0qUsuD9mpoPez0LT0VrWBZLstNjCyvFiCc62ZNKT/waMDFwrlL1nLjfMIqQe4cElb5Aw) or [**jqplay.org**](https://jqplay.org/s/-jToMkleLM)

Answer (score 0):

## Axiom, 92 bytes

```
g(a,b)=="The hypotenuse of this right triangle is "((round((a^2+b^2)^.5*1.e3)/1.e3)::String)
```

test

```
(4) -> g(12, 19)
   (4)  "The hypotenuse of this right triangle is 22.472"
                                                             Type: String
```

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 53 characters

```
"The hypotenuse of this right triangle is "|nOt₄*ï₄/«
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9fKSQjVSGjsiC/JDWvtDhVIT9NoSQjs1ihKDM9o0ShpCgzMS89J1UBKKJUk@df8qipRevweiCpf2j1//@mZnrm5lxGxgA)

I could not figure out how to compress 05AB1E strings. :(

**Explanation:**

```
"..."|nOt₄*ï₄/«

     |             Push array of inputs.
      n            Square them.
       O           Get the sum.
        t          Get the square root.
         ₄*        Multiply by 1000
           ï       Convert to integer. This rounds it.
            ₄/     Divide by 1000
"..."         «    Append it to the string.
                   Implicit print.
```

Comment: "The hypotenuse of this triangle is nOt 4"

Comment: compressed string version (i believe it is the most optimal compression here)
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//UcPcR01rQKhhrt6jhkWnJl3YcXjSodX2yUDOo4Y5YJlZQPLopGOTDq08PPnQKiDndJsCUO7whsN7PfP8Sx41tWgdXg8k9Q@t/v8/2lTHJBYA "05AB1E (legacy) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## Petit Computer BASIC, 66 bytes

```
INPUT A,B?"The hypotenuse of this right triangle is ";SQR(A*A+B*B)
```

PTC only displays the first 3 decimal places when printing.

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 51 bytes

```apl
'The hypotenuse of this right triangle is',3⍕|0j1⊥⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKM97b96SEaqQkZlQX5Jal5pcapCfppCSUZmsUJRZnpGiUJJUWZiXnpOqkJmsbqO8aPeqTUGWYaPupY@6psK0v4/jctYwYQrjctcwdAAAA)

`0j1⊥⎕`: Convert the input into base `i`. e.g `a b  ->  b+ai`

`|`: Magnitude

`3⍕`: Round to 3 decimal places

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 24 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
╬Z.-êû$P¿[▐Ä√#╙δdr▼▀Ö☺┐ç
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=ce5a2e2d88962450a85bde8efb23d3eb64721fdf9901bf87&i=3+4%0A4+5&a=1&m=2)

Unpacked, ungolfed, and commented, it looks like this.

```
`1/yyH\fBXNR&X+{.SC`p   print "The hypotenuse of this right triangle is "
:J+                     square and add the inputs
|Q                      square root
3j                      round to 3 places
p                       print
```

[Run this one](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%601%2FyyH%5CfBXNR%26X%2B%7B.SC%60p%09print+%22The+hypotenuse+of+this+right+triangle+is+%22%0A%3AJ%2B++++++++++++++++++%09square+and+add+the+inputs%0A%7CQ+++++++++++++++++++%09square+root%0A3j+++++++++++++++++++%09round+to+3+places%0Ap++++++++++++++++++++%09print&i=3+4%0A4+5&a=1&m=2)

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 76 bytes

```javascript
a=>b=>'The hypotenuse of this right triangle is '+Math.hypot(a,b).toFixed(3)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcqxDsIgEADQX7mtEJWlrnR0c/MHru0BZwjXwNXo12PT9eW98YNtqbzprchKPfiOfpr9NLwSQfptolT2RiABNHGDyjEpaGUsMRMcMlyeqMmd1@B1tk7lwV9azWj7IqVJJpclmnCAuVvb/w)

## Explanation

```javascript
a => b => // the two arguments (curry method)
    `The hypotenuse of this right triangle is // write the text required
    ${Math.hypot(a,b)}` // and use JS Math.hypot function to calculate the hypotenuse.
```

Alternately, if the you spare me the pain of writing this text.

```javascript
f=Math.hypot // is also a valid answer
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG. Note, though, the requirement that the output be rounded to 3 decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 37 bytes

```
`T hypÇQ«e  È ght â0Ø8  `+Nx²¬x3
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=YFSUIGh5cMdRq2UgjyDIESCdZ2h0IOIw2DggiSBgK054sqx4Mw==&input=OAo4)

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 41 bytes

```
+¨ΣŸṗ¤μe₀fı≤ṙ↔ẏ«G¹∫¨J"."msλ‰⁰i*⁰)1000√¤+□
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AVgAp/9odXNr//8rwqjOo8W44bmXwqTOvGXigoBmxLHiiaThuZnihpThuo/Cq0fCueKIq8KoSiIuIm1zzrvigLDigbBpKuKBsCkxMDAw4oiawqQr4pah////NP80)

With rounding being involved, I sure didn't pick the right language for the task...

```
+                              The concatenation of
 ¨...¨                         the compressed prefix for the output
          ms                   with the stringified elements of
            λ‰⁰   )1000        the divmod by 1000 of
                       √       the square root of 
                         +     the sum of
                        ¤ □    the squares of the two arguments
                *⁰             times 1000
               i               converted to an integer
      J"."                     with a period inserted between them.
```

Computing the actual length of the hypotenuse only takes four bytes, rounding to three decimal places takes seventeen bytes, and adding on `The hypotenuse of this right triangle is` to the output takes twenty bytes. 90.244% of this answer is just formatting!

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 51 bytes

```
+." y¢ó³-.n?ãÜPŽýD'9¹i¾5ŠÁ«£¿9WhI‚".R@s^RJ2QJ3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AU4Asf9weXRo//8rLiIgeQLCohoOw7PCsy0ubhY/w6PDnFDCjsO9RCc5wrkCacK@NcKKw4HCq8Kjwr85V2hJwoIiLlJAc15SSjJRSjP//zcsMjQ)

---

The actual math only takes up 8 bytes.

Despite having built-in string compression capabilities, Pyth is pretty bad at compressing strings.

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 28 bytes

```
ÆḊær3“¡ÆC⁷⁺ɱSoṿȤç½?⁶Ẏtḍỵŀ»,K
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AUYAuf9qZWxsef//w4bhuIrDpnIz4oCcwqHDhkPigbfigbrJsVNv4bm/yKTDp8K9P@KBtuG6jnThuI3hu7XFgMK7LEv///8zLCA0)

### How it works

```
ÆḊær3“¡ÆC⁷⁺ɱSoṿȤç½?⁶Ẏtḍỵŀ»,K - Main link. Takes a pair [a, b] as input
ÆḊ                           - Take the norm √(a²+b²)
  ær3                        - Round the 3 decimal places
     “¡ÆC⁷⁺ɱSoṿȤç½?⁶Ẏtḍỵŀ»   - "The hypotenuse of this right triangle is"
                          ,  - Pair the string with the norm
                           K - Insert a space between the two
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 72 bytes

```rust
|a,b|print!("The hypotenuse of this right triangle is {:.3}",a.hypot(b))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcpBCoQwDEDRvafIuEqhFEGZhTK3mAtUaGzAidLGxaCevYqLv3n8tGUtJPDzLGj2OShQT4L07uyd@ZTD2/FYE4u@sP7GAPG/LhpkywEWAo2cIfEUFTSxl2kOcMveu/asrXfPjaMxZagIW9fYzjVmqM5yAQ)

Woohoo, rust has built-ins for this. The `hypot` method calculates the hypotenuse between the numbers. Instead of the usual `"{}"` format substitution I used `"{:.3}"` which forces the number to display with three decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 108 bytes

```go
import(."fmt";."math")
func f(a,b float64){Printf("The hypotenuse of the triangle is %.3f\n",Sqrt(a*a+b*b))}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY7BCoJAGITvPsWyEezaJpgSQS8R1LHLr-yvS-6u6e8hpCfpIkG3Xqi3yczTMMPwzTyehR_eNeQXKDSzYNyrI1zvPpWxtW9IRBwt8X3ELVDJZYCdyxkKUBnDygNtU9kfGuMIBT-VmpW32pN2XauZR0ZjQo0BV1SamZYtowTPjqvjdURDCKsszKS8z5uLCf47IWQfoIhVPA6KRKVychsZzNVh-OsX)

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno) `Kj`, \$ 46 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 37.86 bytes

```
AO3Zu"The hypotenuse of this right triangle is
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_WbSSd5ZS7IKlpSVpuhY39Rz9jaNKlUIyUhUyKgvyS1LzSotTFfLTFEoyMosVijLTM0oUSooyE_PSc1IVMoshuqCaFyw25jKBMAE)

Not having string compression really hurts in challenges like these.

##### Explanation

```
           # Implicit input
AO         # Push the hypotenuse of the inputs (yes, this is a built-in)
  3Zu      # Round to three decimal places
     "...  # Push the string
           # Flags join the stack by spaces
           # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `j`, 35 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ÆH3ȯ‘The hypotenuse of ċṠ Ṗṇ ġḳ is
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faGm0UpZS7IKlpSVpuhY3DQ-3eRifWP-oYUZIRqpCRmVBfklqXmlxqkJ-msKR7oc7Fyg83Dnt4c52hSMLH-7YrJBZrLCkOCm5GKp9wRJLLkMDCBsA)

4 bytes (`ÆH3ȯ`) for the main bit, and 31 bytes for the compressed string.

##### Explanation

```python
ÆH3ȯ‘...  # Implicit input
ÆH        # Compute hypotenuse
  3ȯ      # Round to 3 d.p.s
    ‘...  # Push compressed string
          # Join the stack
          # Implicit output
```