# Generating Word Grids

Tags: code-golf, string, random

Given input `n`, produce a word grid of size `n`, in as few bytes as possible.

### Details

The number provided will always be odd. The centre square of the grid must always be empty (a space character). The letters that fill the grid must be chosen at random from the [English Scrabble letter distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrabble_letter_distributions) of letters. That is, each tile must be chosen at random, with uniform probability, from the following 100 characters:

```
??EEEEEEEEEEEEAAAAAAAAAIIIIIIIIIOOOOOOOONNNNNNRRRRRRTTTTTTLLLLSSSSUUUUDDDDGGGBBCCMMPPFFHHVVWWYYKJXQZ
```

where `?` denotes blank tiles.

As with a Scrabble board, some tiles in this board will also be bonus tiles for a higher score. These tiles are only visible on a board with a size of 9 or more. and should be visible every 3 rows from the centre square in a pattern emanating outwards, but should never appear on the outermost letters. Bonus squares are denoted using lowercase letters, with blank tiles identified as `!` instead of `?`. Please see [this visual demonstration](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/dom111/e3131296b4cb6c7a5924/raw/663ff64514e6d6361baa804007ab937b9fe7fead/detail.txt) or the [reference implementation](https://tio.run/##hZNJb9swEIXv@hWvigpIcKPaKXJSEqdtuqRLuiRdXR8UmY5lUJRNUggCw7/dnaFk1XZalN@Fy7wZzhM1E1oerlbFHQKFYxxdXp2dX5wkHm2c6vLW0F4Y1UsprBWad@a3YR99vPgHT@9xfo8PO1xs8HmDqw3eNVw2fGk4a3jleEY8J94TH4mXxGviK/GN@EG8xRt8xyf8pNa8PYxLnQmUoxFUVVxTj16lpDAGIZnyEAcRFh5oBKrTSbwlS2RZzmAnuqxuJkilRCakNHEce5QMbGeBsBvHnGEfvahNwaYOgmJINg6GVJ031xL5V4kbe6Dc6WiUqxuk0KkalQXqL4KxprmdCMjcWNgSIs0mrbStuH8yCCTXDZovOeA0Ya/bjegiHLrk3pp4hcc4cJp6RjoffkIXEcXM3rl6mVBc38yrVAt25bpUlWnWhh9NYGyqLT@iMKwTRa43cvVJhA565AB3H3JszndzgoQXR1g74ZadY5YsWsOcZLopmW5LplsSHvmYzuv2ctfadAgxh9/3t7z@Y1obRc0/8JM2ZNnOhDTiv1qZ7ZaNdnM569fvgGIRut9vfa@ZzpXF6YKPlo/g/1I@P8TVqnf4Gw) for more examples on how to correctly distribute bonus tiles.

### Examples

Input: `5`

Output:

```
VNZNT
IFOSN
UD VD
ZIOO?
KTLED
```

Input: `9`

Output:

```
UWDESTKPW
ItDBaDEdI
TERMDYSTR
ROANJLEFT
EkCI OOsT
IPAJPGM?Y
MZLORETVI
G!EGgPUeI
MNROYOEER
```

[Reference implementation](https://tio.run/##hZNJb9swEIXv@hWvigpIcKPaKXJSEqdtuqRLuiRdXR8UmY5lUJRNUggCw7/dnaFk1XZalN@Fy7wZzhM1E1oerlbFHQKFYxxdXp2dX5wkHm2c6vLW0F4Y1UsprBWad@a3YR99vPgHT@9xfo8PO1xs8HmDqw3eNVw2fGk4a3jleEY8J94TH4mXxGviK/GN@EG8xRt8xyf8pNa8PYxLnQmUoxFUVVxTj16lpDAGIZnyEAcRFh5oBKrTSbwlS2RZzmAnuqxuJkilRCakNHEce5QMbGeBsBvHnGEfvahNwaYOgmJINg6GVJ031xL5V4kbe6Dc6WiUqxuk0KkalQXqL4KxprmdCMjcWNgSIs0mrbStuH8yCCTXDZovOeA0Ya/bjegiHLrk3pp4hcc4cJp6RjoffkIXEcXM3rl6mVBc38yrVAt25bpUlWnWhh9NYGyqLT@iMKwTRa43cvVJhA565AB3H3JszndzgoQXR1g74ZadY5YsWsOcZLopmW5LplsSHvmYzuv2ctfadAgxh9/3t7z@Y1obRc0/8JM2ZNnOhDTiv1qZ7ZaNdnM569fvgGIRut9vfa@ZzpXF6YKPlo/g/1I@P8TVqnf4Gw).

### Rules

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest code in bytes wins.

- Any reasonable format can be used for I/O, assuming it is consistent.
- You should be able to handle grids at least up to 999.
- All [standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061/9365) are forbidden.

Comment: I actually contemplated adding a scrabble letter-set yield to Jelly a while back :p

Comment: Should these not be called letter grids, if we're just being placing tiles randomly without actually having to form any words?

Comment: @Shaggy So, I originally wanted to make the challenge about solving these as per [this sandbox post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13914/9365), but when making scripts to generate these and validate the co-ordinates, I thought they'd make fun challenges on their own, I didn't update the name of the challenge as I worked it back though... Perhaps you're right!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>67 65 64 66 64</s>  63 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
”?;ØAx“³Ċu~Ṿr¥rṇ⁽ȦƑ’ḃ12¤µŒl⁾?!yW,WKF€
H3ṬṚ¤ṁ‘1¦ṚŒḄ0,0j«þ`ị¢X€€Y
```

A monadic link taking a number and returning a list of characters, or a full program printing the result.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AX4Agf9qZWxsef//4oCdPzvDmEF44oCcwrPEinV@4bm@csKlcuG5h@KBvcimxpHigJnhuIMxMsKkwrXFkmzigb4/IXlXLFdLRuKCrApIM@G5rOG5msKk4bmB4oCYMcKm4bmaxZLhuIQwLDBqwqvDvmDhu4vColjigqzigqxZ////MTU)** (I prefer it using `G` rather than `Y` since [that's more square](https://tio.run/##AX4Agf9qZWxsef//4oCdPzvDmEF44oCcwrPEinV@4bm@csKlcuG5h@KBvcimxpHigJnhuIMxMsKkwrXFkmzigb4/IXlXLFdLRuKCrApIM@G5rOG5msKk4bmB4oCYMcKm4bmaxZLhuIQwLDBqwqvDvmDhu4vColjigqzigqxH////MTU))

#### How?

```
”?;ØAx“³Ċu~Ṿr¥rṇ⁽ȦƑ’ḃ12¤µŒl⁾?!yW,WKF€ - Link 1, getLetterSets: no arguments
”?                                    - literal '?'
   ØA                                 - yield uppercase alphabet
  ;                                   - concatenate
                       ¤              - nilad followed by link(s) as a nilad:
      “³Ċu~Ṿr¥rṇ⁽ȦƑ’                  -   base 250 number
                    ḃ12               -   converted to bijective base 12 (frequencies)
     x                                -   times (repeat each)
                        µ             - start a new monadic chain, call that uppers
                         Œl           - to lower-case
                           ⁾?!        - literal ['?','!']
                              y       - translate (change '?'s to '!'s)
                               W      - wrap (that) in a list
                                 W    - wrap (uppers) in a list
                                ,     - pair
                                  K   - join with a space, ' '
                                   F€ - flatten €ach (both flattens the wrapped lists
                                      -               AND makes the lone ' ' into [' '])

H3ṬṚ¤ṁ‘1¦ṚŒḄ0,0j«þ`ị¢X€€Y - Main link: number, n                 e.g. 13
H                         - halve                                     6.5
    ¤                     - nilad followed by link(s) as a nilad:
 3                        -   literal three                           3
  Ṭ                       -   untruth                                 [0,0,1]
   Ṛ                      -   reverse                                 [1,0,0]
     ṁ                    - mould like (implicit range(int(right)))   [1,0,0,1,0,0]
        ¦                 - sparse application:
       1                  - ...to indices: 1
      ‘                   - ...action: increment                      [2,0,0,1,0,0]
         Ṛ                - reverse                                   [0,0,1,0,0,2]
          ŒḄ              - bounce                          [0,0,1,0,0,2,0,0,1,0,0]
            0,0           - literal [0,0]                             [0,0]
               j          - join                          [0,0,0,1,0,0,2,0,0,1,0,0,0]
                  `       - repeat left argument as right argument with:
                 þ        -   outer product using:       [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                «         -     minimum                   [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                          -                               [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                          -                               [0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0],
                          -                               [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                          -                               [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                          -                               [0,0,0,1,0,0,2,0,0,1,0,0,0],
                          -                               [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                          -                               [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                          -                               [0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0],
                          -                               [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                          -                               [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                          -                               [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]
                    ¢     - call the last link (1) as a nilad (the letter sets)
                   ị      - index into - gets the correct letter sets for each cell
                     X€€  - random-choice for €ach cell in €ach row
                        Y - join with newlines
                          - if running as a full program: implicit print
```

Comment: I don't think this replaces `?` with `!` when they are in the bonus tile position, I ran a few sets (easier to spot in the `9`s!) Sorry...

Comment: @DomHastings `⁾?!y` means exactly that, but it seems to fail.

Comment: @DomHastings you are correct there is a bug (since the list of uppercase-letters is wrapped in a list at the point I attempt to perform the translation it never sees the `?`s) I will fix it up right now...

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>288</s> <s>281</s> <s>267</s> <s>257</s> <s>225</s> 214 bytes

*thanks to @cole for -1 byte, reordering the `?` to collapse the 2 into `rep(2,10)`*

*-10 bytes realizing that `row(m) == t(col(m))`*

*-41 bytes thanks to user2390246 for reconfiguring the weights, golfing down the indexing, and some more usual R tips*

```r
function(n){m=matrix(sample(el(strsplit("EOAINRTLSUDGBCMPFHVW?YKJXQZ","")),n^2,T,rep(c(12,8,9,6,4:1),c(1,1:4,1,10,5))),,n)
K=n/2+.5
L=col(m)
m[i]=chartr("A-Z?","a-z!",m[i<-(x=!(L-K)%%3&L-1&L-n)&t(x)])
m[K,K]=" "
m}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY7bSsNAEIbv8xTtQssszqobW2tKl1K1nhLP9VSJEGNKF7KbsFkxKj57XBW98WIG5vtmht80uXw0iXkFojK7LJ4qQr1Fa8SaxbNOrSw0aPquhEqskTVUiSrzDLIcKmuqMpcWyPR0cnhyMYsur3b3t3eOz/YOrm/Gd@HR7fmcICGUon7wcYYmKyEF7uMWBriJvSGn6Gbkwx66vo596nZRUy8Ues1fWe17kUiLHBT11L2MRbpMjDVAJmw@dp8T9tYm6MyIQS3aELGQdjob3YhxV5p2LdQ0/roNMYwFaRFPfTQvRtoMFjCgLhsOsMpK4UJ6vzz45sE/zn8E/zPNJw)

Returns a matrix. Fairly simple implementation; samples n^2 values with the proper distribution, stores as an `nxn` matrix.

`K` is the index of the center.

`L=col(m)` is a matrix indicating the column number of each element in the matrix. Hence we compute `!(L-K)%%3` to get the possible columns (including the edges), i.e., those a multiple of 3 away from the center column. To remove the edges, we consider `L-1` and `L-n`. `L-1` is `0` (false) for the first column and `L-n` is `0` for the last column. Applying `&` (element-wise boolean `AND`) to these three yields a matrix with `TRUE` in those columns a multiple of three away from the center, excluding the edges. We store this result as `x`.

If we take the transpose of `x`, `t(x)`, we get the same matrix, but for the rows, hence `x&t(x)` is a matrix we save as `i` containing: `TRUE` indices for the required cells, and `FALSE` everywhere else.

Then we use `chartr` to perform the required transformation on `m[i]` and save the result as `m[i]`, change the center cell to a space, and return the matrix.

Importantly as [user2390246 pointed out](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/142531/generating-word-grids/142541#comment349455_142541), we don't need to test `n>=9` because for `n<7`, there aren't any cells a multiple of 3 away from the center (apart from the center which is changed to a space anyway), and for `n==7`, the only cells a multiple of 3 from the center are on the edge so they are excluded. Neat!

Comment: Could you move the `?` to the part of the string corresponding to `rep(2,9)` and just increase that to `rep(2,10)`?

Comment: @cole yes, that would be I think -1 byte?

Comment: Looks like it, since you remove 2 without `2,` and gain 1 for `10`.

Comment: For the letter distribution: `rep(c(12,8,9,6,4:1),c(1,1:4,1,10,5))` saves 10 bytes. (You'll need to switch the order of the letters to EOAI...)

Comment: @user2390246 wow, thanks!

Comment: You can also cut down the indexing for i by only taking the transform once: `!(x=((L-K)%%3|L%in%c(1,n))|t(x))`

Comment: @user2390246 I had just started getting there but I used `!((x=(L-K)%%3)|t(x))&(y=L-1&L-n)&t(y)`, so combining the two approaches gets us to `i<-(x=!(L-K)%%3&L-1&L-n)&t(x)` which is like 20 bytes shorter!

Comment: I think that, with n < 9, this indexing is still valid (returns all FALSE), so you can get rid of the `if` statement. Also, there's the classic `el(x)` to replace `x[[1]]`.

Comment: @user2390246 oh yeah...thanks for all the help :)

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>247</s> 242 bytes

*-5 bytes with help from @Shaggy*

```js
n=>[...Array(p=n*n)].map((_,i)=>i==p>>1?" ":g(i/n|0)&g(i%n,c="AI9O8NRTEE6LSUD4G3BCMPFHVWY?2KJXQZ".replace(/(\D+)(\d)/g,(_,c,i)=>c.repeat(i))[Math.random()*100|0])?c<"A"?"!":c.toLowerCase():++i%n?c:c+`
`,g=x=>x&&x<n-1&((n>>1)-x)%n%3==0).join``
```

### Test Snippet

```js
let f=
n=>[...Array(p=n*n)].map((_,i)=>i==p>>1?" ":g(i/n|0)&g(i%n,c="AI9O8NRTEE6LSUD4G3BCMPFHVWY?2KJXQZ".replace(/(\D+)(\d)/g,(_,c,i)=>c.repeat(i))[Math.random()*100|0])?c<"A"?"!":c.toLowerCase():++i%n?c:c+`
`,g=x=>x&&x<n-1&((n>>1)-x)%n%3==0).join``

;(R.onclick=L.onchange=I.oninput=function(){let n=+I.value,res=f(n);O.innerText=n+"\n"+(L.checked?res.replace(/[A-Z\?]/g,".").replace(/[a-z!]/g,"#"):res);})()
```

```html
<label><input id=L type=checkbox> Layout only</label> <button id=R>Rerun</button><br><input id=I type=range min=9 max=53 step=2 value=9 style="width:100%">
<pre id=O></pre>
```

Comment: You should be able to save a couple of bytes by moving the assignment of `c` within one of the calls to `g`.

Comment: Really like the slider and layout functionality!

Comment: @Shaggy Thanks, I was able to save some more by improving the ternary expressions too.

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), <s>246</s> 244 + 1 (`-n`) = <s>247</s> 245 bytes

```perl
$m=($n=$_-$_%2)/2;for(@a=(U x++$n)x$n){$_=(LUU,ULU,UUL)[$m%3]x($n/3).U x($n%3)if$z%@a&&$z%3==$m%3;substr$_,$m,1,$"if$m==$z++;s/L/-U/g;s/U/substr"EEAIONRT"x6 .AIJKQXZG."AIO?BCFHMPVWYGUUSSLLDD"x2,rand 100,1/ge;s/^-//;s/-\?/!/g;s/-(.)/lc$1/ge;say}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYxbT8JAEIX/Sm2mpJvudnoJvjQbQEFEF2@43rWpCoSEtqSFpGD8666jPJyckznfnNW0WraNgVy6UEhIBaROxDBKZmXldjPpaqvxPChYQ/qCVLpKa64VSSv2DLkTvzb0ijHzCaXkxGwxg53TzVotsljKPyipN@/1uoKUQ85DDjYxOVU7z0tqVCg0zilo3HP2YNAbXV7c3NrNoeX3Rmfn1w9PQ9@mY@fo@OR0fHV3/zjUejJRqt@3m4hXWfFphUHAQ5xPaelNIJKJlw4e/E8L12e4/IB9n22/jQnjn3K1XpRFbcS47QdhYETxCw)

Comment: Fixed it now along with a few other things.

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), <s>162</s> <s>161</s> <s>154</s> 153 bytes

```perl6
{(my@b=0,|(-$^m..$m).map({$_%%3+!$_}),0).map:{((my$e='AIJKQXZG'~'NRTBCFHMPVWYG'x 2~'EEEAAIIOONRTUSLD'x 4)~'??',$e.lc~'!!',' ')[@b Xmin$_]».comb».roll}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY7NTsJAFIXX9CluySV3RuqkAaKJpIGqFYsC/osabShpE0ynJXVjU6Yv5o4Xq0NXJ/nOd5KzjfLkpJYFYAxOXTJZjEPHtnbsGL@kECi5kKstKzHodPpdEwPFLbthZyXTNkYOuf705n75PqGK5g9P5xdX17O7l9e3Cf1CryLP81zX9xcL3T0/3l5qOuAVjUZkYSSSdUWmSRYB8Y9xCEu5STH43P@JdSZDHXmWJErVcZaDLcQplEbrZ1VAOwUH9KujXrev2kOjdRAwZhjwg9I44jvbpLpSzYTxoaHqfw)

Takes (n-3)/2 as input, returns a list of lists of letters.

Explanation:

```perl6
-> $m {
    # Idea stolen from @Xcali's answer.
    my $e = 'AIJKQXZG' ~ 'NRTBCFHMPVWYG' x 2 ~ 'EEEAAIIOONRTUSLD' x 4;
    # Array containing 1 for bonus tiles, 2 for middle element, like
    #     (0,1,0,0,1,0,0,2,0,0,1,0,0,1,0)
    my @b = 0, |(-$m..$m).map({ $_ %% 3 + !$_ }), 0;
    # Map column vector.
    @b.map: {
        # Compute element-wise minimum of row vector and value from
        # column vector. Select character pools accordingly and get
        # random items.
        ($e~'??', $e.lc~'!!', ' ')[@b Xmin $_]».comb».roll
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

#### [C64 basic v2, <strike>210</strike> 209 bytes]

```
1t$="2?9E3E9A9I8O6N6R6T4L4S4U4D3G2B2C2M2P2F2H2V2W2Y1K1J1X1Q1Z":rEn
3fOx=1ton:fOy=1ton:a=rN(0)*100:b=1
4c=aS(mI(t$,b,1))-48:d=aS(mI(t$,b+1,1)):b=b+2:ifc>atH6
5a=a-c:gO4
6pO983+40*y+x,c:nE:nE:pO1003.5+n*20.5,32
```

An input `n` 5 can be specified like

```
0dA5
```

That "5" to the end should be changed to any odd number. Don't give more than 25, then the program will overwrite itself.

---

How to try it: google for "vice c64 emulator", install it, and copy-paste this basic code into it. To start the program, type: `RUN`. To clear the screen, press shift/home.

And the result:

[image]

Comment: What's the best way for me to validate this and apply the input? :)

Comment: @DomHastings C64 emulator with a monitor (monitors are byte-level memory modifiers in the c64 world), or the help plus plus basic extender. I am not 100% sure that it will work, but 90 yes.

Comment: @DomHastings I can make a 3 byte longer, debuggable version. The important thing is that the common basic commands are given here in tokenized form. The token is always very simple: first char of the command + the second char in uppercase. For example, `FOR` is tokenzied as `fO`. Or `GOTO` as `gO`. I could have made it also interactive, but unfortunately the `INPUT` command is an exception, it doesn't have a token. This is why the input should be given with `DATA` command, whose token is `dA`.

Comment: I'd certainly love to see it in action, any way you can help me get to see it would be awesome! Ah, thanks for explaining, that make it read better to me. I'll come back to this in the morning!!

Comment: @DomHastings Don't need, it is ready. :-) There were some minor bugs, I fixed them and the result become 1 byte smaller! In asm, it could have been only roughly 40 byte. Although I had to use some tricky way to the random generation.

Comment: Thank you for explaining and thank you for the screen shot! I'll play with this tomorrow as I'm quite intrigued, but thanks for indulging my questions!

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>214</s> <s>236</s> 240 bytes

```python
lambda n:[[[choice([s,[[c.lower(),'!'][c<'A']for c in s]][((i-n//2)%3+(j-n//2)%3<1)*(i*j>0)*(i<n-1)*(j<n-1)])," "][i==j==n//2]for j in range(n)]for i in range(n)]
from random import*
s=(("OIAE"*2+"SDLUNTRE")*2+"HVBMCYPWF?GNTR")*2+"ZXJQKGIA"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY9Jb8IwEIXPza9wLVWxQ4ACUg8IF4Ut7PseckhDUhyBg@xIVX99aqfQ5bu8N08zT5rrZ3KKWSUNySE9e5e3owdY1XEc/xRTP0COMKUvnOOPgCNs6o@66/g13dLdMObAB5QB4boOQjTPisUyfqrkUHS3tRI2EDWi12elNZZXc5Spi00IoOtQQiJC1H5WGKlC7rH3ADGcJfRfooU8vqjxKIVerjFPDE0QhOCkZ7WhUc7BRWu4Gi/nbYjV1F03Rs3ddNOp2zL8zvbb/mxg9yyYekIEPAFC1gRHJDAhNwvr9fYfrDu9O5Mb44x5xjJjKFlIVpKWxLbtRqPZHI2m006n212vN5vdbtDfzvYQa@pD9vthySy9mGVc1R6unLIEyJd/LDwwWIhiyhC8KcdA3XN1H8pVjNMv)

The multiplicity of each character is expressed as sum of powers of two, e.g `12 = 8 + 4 => "E"*12 = "E"*2*2*2 + "E"*2*2`.

`((i-n//2)%3+(j-n//2)%3<1)*(i*j>0)*(i<n-1)*(j<n-1)` may probably be golfed.

Comment: @Giuseppe I will fix it

Comment: I like the extra clarification via the assert!

Comment: @Giuseppe I hope it's ok now. `i<n` was always true, even when `i=n-1` (bottom). Same for `j`.

Comment: looks good to me! +1.